# How to execute a function from a Window to another Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have this code in my MainWindow.xaml.cs

Page2 myPage = new Page2();

myPage.ShowData();

Basically, it should implement the function from another class since the function is declared as public and should be accessed by another class, but when I try to execute it it doesn't do anything. It hits the breakpoint but the function is not executed.

In my Page2.xaml.cs I have,

public void ShowData()
{
textBox1.Text = "Test";
}

Answer (score 1):

Check whether invocation is required by calling `textBox1.InvokeRequired`. If that value is `true`, you've to call `textBox1.Invoke([Delegate function]);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what do I put on Delegate function argument?